# Power Series of $\sin x$, how to show positive.

Tags: analysis

I have been asked to show that $S(x)$, the power series for $\sin x$, is $>0$ for $0 < x \le \sqrt6$.

I have altered the series into the form $$\left(\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}-\frac{x^{4n+3}}{(4n+3)!}\right)$$

but am unsure how to go on? Seeing as $x$ is never zero, I thought about taking the first term outside of a bracket, leaving $1-\frac{x^2}{(4n+3)(4n+2)}$, but I'm just not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Better check the *quotient* ((x^(4*n+1))/(4*n+1)!)/((x^(4*n+3))/(4*n+3)!).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This follows from your observation, the series for $\sin$ 
$$\sin(x) = x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5+\cdots =
x(1-\frac{1}{6}x^2)+\frac{1}{120}x^5 \pm \cdots
$$
and the fact that $(1-\frac{1}{6}x^2)$ is positive for $ 0 \le x \le \sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: Starting with the second term the terms of the sine series decrease in absolute value even for $0<x<\sqrt{20}$.